# Deleting duplicated fields within record

Tags: awk

`enter code here`I want to delete duplicate instances of the key (the first 2 fields) in each record. For my specific the duplicates actually appear reversed.

So given

```
a b b a stuff1 b a stuff2 stuff3 b a
```

where each space is a tab

I want:

```
a b stuff1 stuff2 stuff3
```

and I thought this would do it:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
     {gsub($2 "\t" $1,"")}
     1' file
```

Alternative solutions are welcome but I am particularly interested in why that does not work
(I have tried it with a dynamic regexp and with `gensub` btw).

Per a previous question I am aware that I may/will end up with duplicate tabs and will take care of that outside `awk`.

**EDIT**

Solutions so far don't work so here is the real data. For ^ read a tab character

```
1874    ^Passage de Venus^  <DIRECTORS> ^Passage de Venus^  1874^   Janssen, P.J.C.^    <keywords>^ Passage de Venus^   1874^   astronomy^  astrophotography^   <genres>^   Short
```

What I want is

```
1874^   Passage de Venus^   <DIRECTORS>^    Janssen, P.J.C.^    <keywords>^ astronomy^  astrophotography^   <genres>^   Short
```

Comment: Please, post a few records which your code does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this

```
awk '{gsub($2 "[[:space:]]+" $1, "")}1' file
```

If this works and using `"\t"` doesn't you probably aren't using tabs .

Checked again there is no bug it is likely you just have space in you file next to the tabs

Try

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *\t *"}{gsub($2 FS $1, "")}1' file
```

Although this answer was purely meant to be for troubleshooting whyt gsub was not working, i have decided to add this addendum for Eds concerns in the comments

This will stop words other than exactly `$2` then `$1` being matched, and should also sort out the formatting messing up

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" *\t *"}{$0=gensub("("FS")" $2 FS $1 "("FS")","\\1","g")}1' file
```

#### Example

```
 Input
 1234    mal     mal     1234    formal  12345678        blah

 Output
 1234    mal     formal  12345678        blah
```

This should be more robust again even with metachars

```
awk -F' *\t *' '{x=y;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)(i>2&&$i==$2&&$(i+1)==$1&&i++)||x=x?x"\t"$i:$i;$0=x}1' file
```

Comment: Yes I figured something like this would work but really wanted to know why the simpler solution doesn't. So it is because of a bug in awk?

Comment: @IheOnwuka Checked again there were spaces in you example before the first tab, updated answer should work

Comment: @IheOnwuka Does it have `^` in the data the same as your example, because there is a space between one of them and the tab ?

Comment: Yes $2 has a space before the field separator. I was forced to insert it in order to make a join work and I had forgotten it was there.

Comment: Just be aware it'll delete the wrong text given some input values, e.g. RE metacharacters in either of the first 2 fields, or if the text from either field just happens to partially match the text in other fields that happen to be adjacent to each other (e.g. if $1=`1234` and $2=`mal` and somewhere in the text you have `formal<tab>12345678` then that will become `for5678`). Unfortunately you really need to use a string match, not a regexp match, and include bounding chars for a robust solution to this kind of problem. If you find you need that, let us know.

Comment: Just change the last `"("FS")"` to `"("FS"|$)"` and I think the only remaining issue would be RE metacharacters in the fields. Ah, wait - when using FS like that you could have a problem with `\t` needing to be `\\t` in that dynamic regexp context.

Comment: @EdMorton Yeah metacharacters would still be a problem, dunno what you mean about the `\\t` though. I think this is creating a new question that OP didn't ask anyway though so i'm just gonna leave it now unless they have complaints.

Comment: wrt `\\t` - when an RE is stored in a string it is a dynamic regexp and so is parsed twice, once when the awk script is read and again when it is executed, so anything that needs to be escaped in a static regexp `$0 ~ /a\tb/` needs to be escaped twice in a dynamic regexp `$0 ~ "a\\tb"` or `var="a\\tb"; ...; $0 ~ var`. Yeah, no point pursuing this if the OP thinks they don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @EdMorton I lied, i made one anyway coz i was bored ha, let me know if you think this will still break :) P.S just seen your answer and it looks pretty much the same(ish) so i must be on the right track for what you wanted !

Comment: Yeah, looks about right to me, I'm not sure if the increment on i when the match is found should be plus 1 or plus 2 though. Having the condition at the end be `$0=x` will delete blank lines from the file, not sure if that's an issue. Oh, and remember to re-init x and pre-populate x with $1 OFS $2 and start the loop at 3 or you'll get undesirable results of $1 == $2. of course then you'd have the same answer I do... :-)

Comment: @EdMorton incrementing one is correct as the loop itself also increments one and doesn't add to x unless it doesn't increment.Like you said dunno about blank lines. I did forget to set x back to blank as i only used one line in the file, but starting the loop at 1 will not cause a problem unless the first two fields are the same which looks unlikely in OPs example.

Answer (score 4):

Your attempt was good, you probably have some problems with spaaces/tabs. Also, you may want to use `FS` to make it more changeable:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} {gsub($2 FS $1, "")}1' file
             |____________________^
```

So if you notice that the field separator is another one, just change it in your `BEGIN` block and it will work fine.

#### Test

```
$ cat a
a b b a stuff1 b a stuff2 stuff3 b a
$ awk '{gsub($2 FS $1, "")}1' a
a b  stuff1  stuff2 stuff3
```

Comment: Am i missing something ? This shouldn't make any difference ??

Comment: FS is a space(or whatever it has been set to) when used like that,using a tab instead would make no difference.

Comment: Yes it doesn't make a difference. Still doesn't work with actual data.

Comment: Can't use comma because it appears in the data. Used backtick `. Still doesn't work with my data.

Comment: @IheOnwuka maybe you can try with the pipe: `|`. Also, make perfect sure you do not have any trailing spaces around.

Comment: @jidder. Your deleted post was actually the right answer. If you put it back up I will accept it and explain.

Answer (score 1):

This is the kind of solution you really need as it does string comparisons on full fields and so will not falsely match when fields contain RE metacharacters or when fields start or end with the same values as $1/$2:

```
awk -F' *\t *' -v OFS='\t' '{
    rec = $1 OFS $2
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( ($i == $2) && ($(i+1) == $1) ) {
            i += 2
        }
        else {
            rec = rec OFS $i
        }
    }
    print rec
}
' file
```

Its untested as idk if you'll care about the solution being robust or not - test yourself and massage to suit....

Comment: Thanks. This was quite timely as it appeared just as I ran into an RE metacharacter abort. But I do not need something something this robust  and so have gone with  $2!~/[[]/ {gsub($2 FS $1,"")} which I will fix as I encounter more metacharacters in the file.

Comment: That approach almost always ends badly in frustration and despair so I would not do it. If your fields can contain undesirable RE metacharacters then simply write your script to use strings instead of REs. If the resulting script is more robust than you feel it has to be, that's not an awful thing.

Comment: I do not want the script to be more complicated than is warranted.   I didn't hit this problem until 160k records into the file, so maybe I will encounter 10 instances out of 1.3m records. For me this is just a try catch workaround because the language lacks error handling.

Comment: OK, just make sure to read every line of output every time you run it then because sometimes when the script behaves undesirably it will not produce any kind of error or warning message but will instead just silently corrupt the output.

Comment: The metacharacter failures are actually serendipitous because some (not all) of them  highlight anomalies that have seeped through. My plan was to flag them so they could be looked at  but this doesn't work well enough as the mechanism is too crude (it catches things that don't fail). Basically I need try catch error handling and may need to move this problem to a language that provides it.

Comment: This problem is about deleting duplicated keys that have accumulated by successive join operations in order to bring the file size down. I solved it my marking up the keys when they were created so that they could be deleted with a simple sed regex at the end. So I am no longer using awk to solve the problem but it has been a very useful learning experience.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I can think of is that your input file is not delimited by tabs

**Test**

```
$ echo "a b b a stuff1 b a stuff2 stuff3 b a" | awk  '{gsub($2" "$1,"")}1'
a b  stuff1  stuff2 stuff3
```